# User registration with Repository pattern

Tags: php, object-oriented, repository

I have been developing a simple login registration page with PHP using the repository pattern. Following are the business rules :

During registration

1. Email must be unique.
2. Email must be a valid email address.

User table columns:
id, name, username, password, created_at, updated_at

**register.php page**

```
if($_POST)
{
    try{

        $input['name'] = $_POST['name'];
        $input['email'] = $_POST['email'];
        $input['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        $input['password'] = $_POST['password'];

        $user_register_obj = new UserRegister(new UserInfoRepository());
        $user_register_obj->register($input);

        header('Location: login.php');
        exit();
    }
    catch(CustomException $e)
    {
        var_dump($e->getCustomMessage());
    }
}

?>
```

Following is the userinfo interface: This is for the user table.
**IUserInfo.php**

```
interface IUserInfo {

    public function getId();
    public function getName();
    public function getEmail();
    public function getUserName();
    public function getCreatedAt();
    public function getUpdatedAt();
    public function getPassword();

}
```

**User.php** file :

```
class User implements IUserInfo{

    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $email;
    private $username;
    private $created_at;
    private $updated_at;
    private $password;

    public function __construct($id,
                                $name,
                                $email,
                                $username,
                                $created_at,
                                $updated_at,
                                $password)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->created_at = $created_at;
        $this->updated_at = $updated_at;
        $this->password = $password;
    }
    public function getEmail()
    {
       return $this->email;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getUserName()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updated_at;
    }
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

UserInfoRepository :

```
interface IUserInfoRepository {

    public function getById($id);
    public function getByEmail($email);
    public function getAll();
    public function insert($input);
    public function update($id, $input);
    public function delete($id);

}
```

This is the repository class for userinfo :

```
class UserInfoRepository implements IUserInfoRepository{

    private $table = 'users';
    private $db_obj;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db_obj = new \DatabaseHandler\Database();
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
        $query = 'select * from users where id = ' . $id;

        return $this->db_obj->GetOneRow($query);
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getAll() method.
    }

    public function getByEmail($email)
    {
        $query = "select * from user where email = '$email'";

        $obj = $this->db_obj->GetOneRow($query);

        if(!$obj)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return new User($obj['id'], $obj['name'], $obj['email'], $obj['username'], $obj['created_at'], $obj['updated_at'], $obj['password']);
        }
    }

    public function insert($input)
    {
        $name = $input['name'];
        $email = $input['email'];
        $username = $input['username'];
        $password = md5($input['password']);

        $query = "insert into user (name, email, username, password) values ('$name', '$email', '$username', '$password' )";
        return $this->db_obj->InsertAndGetId($query);
    }

    public function update($id, $input)
    {
        // TODO: Implement update() method.
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        // TODO: Implement delete() method.
    }
}
```

UserRegister class :

```
class UserRegister {

    private  $userRepo;

    public function __construct(\IUserInfoRepository $userRepo)
    {
        $this->userRepo = $userRepo;
    }

    public function register($input)
    {
        $email = $input['email'];

        $result = filter_var( $email , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
        if(!$result)
            throw new \CustomException("Invalid Email");

        $obj = $this->userRepo->getByEmail($email);
        if(!is_null($obj))
            throw new \CustomException("Email already found");

        $this->userRepo->insert($input);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Please ignore the database handler Database right now. That class seems fine and I am not posting it as it may make it more complex.

Can you please review my code design ? I will accept answer in any languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Security

**SQL Injection**

You are (very likely) open to SQL injection, as you put user input directly into SQL queries. You need to use prepared statements instead. This goes for all statements (select, insert, ...).

**Hashing**

You also have to use a proper password hashing function. md5 hasn't been acceptable for at least 15 years. Use password_hash instead.

### Misc

**Structure**

- your interfaces are unneeded, as they are unlikely to be used in different situations. Your `IUserInfoRepository` may work as a generic `IRepository` though, as likely other objects need to be selected, inserted, etc. Your `IUserInfo` interface could partly work as an `IBaseObject` interface which contains `getId` and possibly `getCreatedAt`and `getUpdatedAt` (if these are values that you store for all objects).
- Your `getById` function returns an array, while your `getByEmail` function returns a `User`. This should be handled the same way.
- You should pass on the specific required fields to `insert`, not just some input array. Arrays are bad for usability, as a user of your class would need to read the documentation, or in your case - as you don't have any - actually look at the code.

**Other**

- add PHPDoc style comments to your functions to explain what the arguments need to be, what the return values are, etc.
- I would throw an exception if an email doesn't exist instead of returning null, to avoid excessive null checks.
- always use curly brackets
- you don't need one-time variables such as `$email = $input['email'];`.
- upper-case your SQL keywords to increase readability
- be less generic with your variable names. `obj` could be `userData`, `query` could be `userSelectQuery`, etc.

Comment: Hi, @tim, Thanks for great review. I have several questions for you. Should I break down the IUserInfoRepository  interface into two interfaces ?  generic IRepository(getById getAll  insert  update  delete) and IUserInfoRepository(getByEmail) ? If I do not use any Interface at all for repository, then I have to type hint UserRepository class in  UserRegister class. Now, UserRepository contains database related code. So, wont that violate dependency inversion principle ?

Comment: @Tanvir Yes, breaking them up (so that `IUserInfoRepository` extends `IRepository`) sounds like a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

I see a little bit weird the use of a in interface on the model of a class (*IUserInfo*). Because it's unlikely that you're going to swap-out the model, it does not have any implementation details.
Also you should not make interfaces with functions that you are not going to implement, like a template interface for all your repositories, and use the same for everyone, and have unimplemented/unused functions.

Also, you could change the names of the variables in this function for something more descriptive, instead of result and obj, you could use userEmailAfterValidation for example.

```
    public function register($input)
{
    $email = $input['email'];

    $result = filter_var( $email , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
    if(!$result)
        throw new \CustomException("Invalid Email");

    $obj = $this->userRepo->getByEmail($email);
    if(!is_null($obj))
        throw new \CustomException("Email already found");

    $this->userRepo->insert($input);

    return true;
}
```